# ORA-00911: invalid character 00911. 00000 - "invalid character" unusual Error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case

While executing below line of query in Oracle using `CASE` statement, I'm getting some unusual error.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT MODEL_NAME, 
       CASE WHEN EQP_TYPE_NAME IN('BAT') THEN MODEL_NAME  END AS EQUIPMENT_MODEL_NAME 
FROM  solar_equipment;
```

and the error is below

> ```
> ORA-00911: invalid character
> 00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
> *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
>            letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
>            character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
>            any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
>            (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
>            delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
>            Reference Manual.
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 4 Column: 1
> ```

Please suggest what is wrong

Comment: How and where are you executing it? Sometimes the trailing semicolon can cause that error (dynamic SQL, JDBC...). Otherwise are you sure that is what is on line 4 - what else is around it?

Comment: i am simply executing in `SQL Worksheet` and its giving me the error

Comment: [Looking at the raw text](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69bd914656f5bf44024e164391fffe38) of your question there seem to be some Unicode replacement characters (efbfbd); maybe you copied and pasted that code from somewhere and had a character set conversion issue along the way or something. If you retype the query does it throw the same error?

Comment: No, retyping is working properly. But why doing copy paste is giving the error ? I just dont get it

Comment: Cannot replicate the error (copy/pasting the code from your question) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9fc658eaa667d1f94bd7ae86799b2fd5).

Comment: @MT0: same is happening with this `Update solar_equipment SET MODEL_NAME = PMODELNAME,
     CASE EQP_TYPE_NAME IN ('BAT') THEN MODEL_NAME END AS EQUIPMENT_MODEL_NAME
     WHERE Request_id = PJOB_ID AND SAP_ID = PSAP_ID;`

Comment: That isn't valid syntax as the `CASE` expression is not updating anything. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca7e18ca41f28259d47b260ad03ff092)

Comment: and the `CASE` expression is missing the `WHEN` keyword and you don't want to use `AS` to alias the expression. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=336393581efceaaf8aa0957c17ce7ded).... but there is no `ORA-00911: invalid character` error.

Comment: @hud - presumably whatever you're copying from and SQL Developer are using different character sets. That's not really an Oracle or coding problem though *8-)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely cause (based on the exchange in comments, about "copying and pasting"):

You copied the whole query from somewhere - most likely a website - where single-quotes aren't the standard apostrophe from the ASCII character set. Instead, they are calligraphic quotes. This applies specifically to the IN clause where you have the string BAT enclosed in single-quotes. That is why if you re-type the query in your editor you don't get that problem.

This problem is masked by the fact that, if you copy the query from *wherever* and paste it in your editor, the quotes are silently translated into standard apostrophe in your GUI (for *displaying* only) - but NOT in the actual query text. And, the problem can originally be caused by someone copying a valid query (with standard ASCII apostrophe) to a website, where the website silently converts those single quotes into calligraphic quotes.

One of the many "benefits" of letting Big Brother do stuff for us without asking us and without even telling us what he's doing...

And, why do you get that specific error? Because the parser interprets every "token" in the query as either a string or a SQL keyword or an identifier (table or column name), etc. When it gets to BAT enclosed in calligraphic quotes, that can't be a hard-coded string, it is not a SQL keyword, etc. - so the parser guesses it's an identifier; but identifiers not enclosed in double-quotes can't begin with a calligraphic left single-quote. So the parser tells you that the "identifier" is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason, this error ALWAYS happens when you paste an Oracle DDL into SQL Developer that was sent via Microsoft Teams chat.

It seems that some hidden invalid characters are added into the code, and the only way to fix this is either manually re-type everything (NOT recommended) or get it via email or some other channel.

Think of the similar case of Microsoft Word automatically changing your straight quote characters for typographic quotes, the latter being illegal in SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM "TABLE_X"
```

Gets converted into:

```
SELECT *
FROM “TABLE_X”
```